# Access Denied (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception) While Calling WCF Service

Tags: wcf, windows-8.1, capability, appcontainer

Hosting the WCF services via a host exe on Windows 8.1 I am getting an AppContainer related error. I cannot find any good documentation on the methods on the top of the stack trace. Kind of grasping at straws here.

"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied\r\n\r\nServer stack trace: \r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.AppContainerInfo.GetCurrentProcessToken()\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.AppContainerInfo.RunningInAppContainer()\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.AppContainerInfo.get_IsRunningInAppContainer()\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeSharedMemory.BuildPipeName(String pipeGuid)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeSharedMemory.get_PipeName()\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeSharedMemory.GetPipeName(AppContainerInfo appInfo)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnectionInitiator.GetPipeName(Uri uri, IPipeTransportFactorySettings transportFactorySettings)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.NamedPipeConnectionPoolRegistry.NamedPipeConnectionPool.GetPoolKey(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationPool`2.TakeConnection(EndpointAddress address, Uri via, TimeSpan timeout, TKey& key)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)\r\n\r\n
Exception rethrown at [0]: \r\n   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)\r\n
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)\r\n
at IAuthenticationService.AuthTempTokens(TokenSet tokens, CAMSSystem systemId, String accountId, String ipAddress, String uniqueId)\r\n
at login_Default.AuthenticateAndRedirect() in c:\Source\RiverTam\Source\Systems\Web\PMI\PMI\Default.aspx.cs:line 167"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the IIS site was configured to impersonate and that user did not have rights! Spotted the user using Process Monitor. Not surprisingly removing following line allowed things to work as my user, an administrator, has rights just fine.

```
<system.web>    
    <identity impersonate="true" username="user" password="password" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to use a named pipe binding and you can't use named pipes in a WinRT based application.

Comment: Yes we are using a named pipe binding, BUT the application is a plain 'ol exe that for some reason is operating in an AppContainer context? The host is not an WinRT based application. That has me baffled.

Comment: Hmm, it might just be *checking* if it's running in an AppContainer then. If we just go with the just the error message, I would say that the user the app is running as doesn't have rights to open the pipe. What is the address you're trying to open? What rights does the user you're running as have? Can you try to run as an admin real quick?

Comment: So the full stack is... Running a coded UI test in VS 2013 against a locally hosted website that is calling a WCF hosted in an EXE at the address net.pipe://localhost/CAMS/AuthenticationService.

I've tried running the EXE as administrator with no effect. The website is running in the ASP.NET Development Server so I'm assuming it's running under my identity and I'm an admin on the machine.